# Kinect - IR pattern looks different with Microsoft SDK than in real

Tags: kinect, infrared

IR pattern looks different when taking sample with Microsoft SDK - have some kind of swatch, but when I take camera and turn IR mode - I can see normal repeating pattern

Questions[]: Why is that?
Has something to do with SDK?..maybe taking samples would be normal with OpenNI (or other Third-party dev)?

With swatch (ellipse/circle):
[url=http://postimg.org/image/gziq6wqbb/][img]http://s7.postimg.org/gziq6wqbb/Kinect_Snapshot_04_29_18.jpg[/img][/url]
[swatch pattern](http://s7.postimg.org/4xnccrh2z/Kinect_Snapshot_04_29_18.jpg)

Normal:
[normal pattern](http://i40.tinypic.com/2rwwc61.jpg)